# How to use a Mutex to share writable memory? cannot move out of dereference of std::sync::MutexGuard

Tags: rust, mutex

Code:

```
pub async fn start_orderbook_updater(websocket: Arc<Mutex<Ws>>) {
    let mut ws = *websocket.lock().unwrap();
```

Error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Ws>`
  --> src/ftx.rs:20:18
   |
20 |     let mut ws = *websocket.lock().unwrap();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  move occurs because value has type `Ws`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                  help: consider borrowing here: `&*websocket.lock().unwrap()`
```

My goal is to be able to pass websocket of type `Ws` to a function. The function will borrow WS mutable, call `subscribe` method on it, which mutates it, and return.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to borrow mut `&mut T`, you can use [`Mutex::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.get_mut)

Or `lock`+[`deref_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-DerefMut) over the [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#)

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0usize));
    
    let mut inner = data.lock().unwrap();
    *inner += 10;
    println!("{}", inner);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=396d50644f965d5d4ccc8e2c54ce18d0)

Your real problem is that you are dereferencing while assigning it, so it is trying to move the value which invalidates the `Arc<Mutex>`. Do not use `*` as per the simple example above:

```rust
let mut ws = websocket.lock().unwrap();
```

Comment: Why can't I do this? 
let mut ws = websocket.lock().unwrap();
let mut x = *ws;

Comment: @SpaceMonkey, because it then tries to **move** the value, not borrow it.

Comment: thank you, how do I make it borrow?  `let mut ws2 = (&mut *ws);`?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey, as in the example. MutexGuard already implements DerefMut, so you can pass it to wherever you need a `&mut Ws`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still struggling to see why then dereferencing using `*ws` returns a `Ws` instead of a `&mut Ws`